# Rails - Render speakers show page inside modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have an events website with a list of speakers on the events show page, I want each speaker to have a link to the speaker show page.

I'm unsure what the link_to method should be, heres what I have so far -

### View

```
  <% @event.speakers.append(nil).each_slice(6) do |speaker_block| %>
    <div class="rowOfSpeakers row">
      <% speaker_block.each_with_index do |speaker, index| %>
        <div class="twocol<%= " last" if index == 5 || index == 11 %>">
         <div>
           <div class="speakerTwitter">
            <%= link_to speaker.twitter, "http://twitter.com/#{speaker.twitter}" %>
           </div>
           <img src="<%= speaker.avatar %>" alt="<%= speaker.name %>">
         </div>

         <!-- Heres my link -->
         <h3><%= link_to speaker.name, event_speaker_path(@speaker) %></h3>

       </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

### The above links results in the following error

```
  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"speakers", :event_id=>nil}
```

### The controller

```
  def show
     @speaker = Speaker.find(params[:id])
  end
```

### Routes

```
  resources :events do
    resources :leads, path: "download", only: [:new, :create]
    resources :registrations, path: "register", only: [:new, :create, :index]
    resources :speakers, only: [:show]
  end
```

Comment: In this case posting your routes config could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= link_to speaker.name, event_speaker_path(@event, speaker) %>`

You're referencing `@speaker` which is a `nil` variable (i.e., it doesn't exists). Look at your `each_with_index` block.

Also, since it's a nested route, you need to specify the "parent", in this case, the `@event`.

Answer (score 0):

For linking to `'speakers#show'` you probably can use `speaker_path(@speaker)`. If you're not sure, you can always run `rake routes` to view all routes available in your application.

Comment: I ran rake routes to get the above routes. Speakers are associated to an event. An event has_and_belongs_to_many :speakers. A Speaker   has_and_belongs_to_many :events